# 2-stride permutation and its inverse in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation, matrix-multiplication

Is there a pain-free way of creating a 2-stride permutation matrix of size `n` in Matlab?

This means I want to find the matrix form of a linear operator `L` such that it acts on

```
x = [x(1), x(2), ..., x(n)]
```

in the following way:

```
L*x = [x(1), x(3), ..., x(n-1), x(2),x(4), ..., x(n)]  % when n is even

L*x = [x(1), x(3), ..., x(n), x(2), x(4), ..., x(n-1)] % when n is odd
```

e.g for n = 4:
the matrix is

```
 [1 0 0 0;
  0 0 1 0;
  0 1 0 0;
  0 0 0 1]
```

or n = 5:

```
[1 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 1 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 1;
 0 1 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 1 0]
```

Extra question: Now I want the inverse of `L`above in operator form (the one-line syntax in the answer). 
In matrix form the inverse is the transposition of matrix of `L`. It is also the `ceil(n/2)` stride permutation.

TL;DR what is the easiest way to produce output to `ceil(n/2)` stride permutation?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but it's likely partly due to you editing your question so that it now deviates from the original! Your "extra question" is a bit vague and confusing, as well as (of course) being "extra" to the original -  making the good answer (which you haven't accepted) incomplete. It would have been better to simply ask another, clear and well described, question

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

The easiest solution is by using the following one-line syntax:

```
result = x([1:2:n,2:2:n]);
```

With n=9 and x=1:9, we get the following result:

```
result =

 1
 3
 5
 7
 9
 2
 4
 6
 8
```

It is also possible to solve it with a linear function, as described below.

**Solution with Linear Operator L**

This problem can be also solved by generating an nxn matrix L, as can be seen in the following example, with n=9:

```
L = zeros(n,n);
L(sub2ind(size(L),1:n,[1:2:n,2:2:n])) = 1;

L =

 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

*Full code example*

```
%input example    
n = 9; x = [1:n]'; 

%generates a matrix L
L = zeros(n,n);
L(sub2ind(size(L),1:n,[1:2:n,2:2:n])) = 1;

%calculates result
result = L*x;
```

*Result*

input

```
x =
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
```

output

```
result =
 1
 3
 5
 7
 9
 2
 4
 6
 8
```